# Which spelling is correct: "benefiting" or "benefitting"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, conjugation, doubled-consonants

Which spelling is correct: *benefiting* or *benefitting*?

Comment: I like *benefitting* more, personally, because *benefiting* looks like the present participle of a verb spelled *benefite*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both spellings are considered to be correct; given the pattern of American English to prefer the shorter of alternate spellings (see color vs. colour; aluminum vs. aluminium), I would summarise that in the US the single-t version would be correct.

However, I see that the two-t version appears more often in searches, so it has popularity going for it.

Comment: It is the one-t version that appears more often in google searches. What search are you using?

Comment: Actually, from [Google](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benefitting%2Cbenefiting&year_start=1800&year_end=2007&corpus=5&smoothing=3) [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=benefitting%2Cbenefiting&year_start=1800&year_end=2007&corpus=6&smoothing=3), *benefitting* seems to be used slightly more frequently in American English than it is in British English. I believe this is because, in American English, the rule is to double the consonant if there is stress on the last syllable, and in American English, *benefit* has secondary stress on the last syllable.

Answer (score 9):

Both are considered correct in the English language. *Benefiting* and *benefitting* both are acceptable due to two different English spelling rules.

If the final syllable is not accented/emphasized and it does not end in an *l* then you do not double the consonant. If you say *ben-e-fit,* you accent *ben,* the first syllable.

I believe it can become *benefitting* as well, due to the other English rule, that if a word ends with a short vowel followed by a consonant, you double the consonant so the vowel doesn’t become long.

Due to these two rules, I guess it can be spelled both ways.

Answer (score 5):

Google found 12.900.000 (approximately) matches for benefiting , but only 1.210.000 for benefitting.

References:

Merriam Webster lists both as correct spelling
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benefitting

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/benefitting

Comment: Thanks for the numbers on the google searches. I've always leaned towards the one-t spelling, seems like most people do.

Answer (score 0):

Benefiting is the correct one in English and American English. There is no entry for 'benefitting' in the Cambridge dictionary, see:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=Benefitting
The reason being we double letters on the end of the word if that is where the emphasis lies. In 'benefit' the emphasis is on the 'n', rather than the last letter.

Comment: I think using a British dictionary for advice about American English is clearly an error. See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benefit). (Even if *Cambridge* is in general a better dictionary.)